# Spring Autowire Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, spring

I have a quartz job running in my web server, configured via Spring as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class StatisticsJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public JobDetailBean jobDetailBean() {
        JobDetailBean jobDetailBean = new JobDetailBean();
        jobDetailBean.setJobClass(StatisticsJob.class);
        jobDetailBean.setBeanName("statisticsJobBean");
        jobDetailBean.setName("statisticsJob");
        jobDetailBean.setGroup("default");
        return jobDetailBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public CronTriggerBean cronTriggerBean(@Qualifier("jobDetailBean") JobDetailBean jobDetailBean) throws ParseException {
        CronTriggerBean cronTriggerBean = new CronTriggerBean();

        cronTriggerBean.setBeanName("cronTriggerBean");
        cronTriggerBean.setJobDetail(jobDetailBean);
        cronTriggerBean.setCronExpression("0/5 * * * * ?");

        return cronTriggerBean;

    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(@Qualifier("cronTriggerBean") CronTriggerBean cronTriggerBean
            , @Qualifier ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactoryBean.setExposeSchedulerInRepository(true);

        schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(cronTriggerBean);

        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

        return schedulerFactoryBean;
    }

    public void setCronExpression(String cronExpression) {
        this.cronExpression = cronExpression;
    }


}
```

(The StatisticsJob class extends QuartzJobBean and implements the executeInternal method).

This job executes successfully as per the cron expression after the server starts. However, I would also like to be able to schedule this job at will, like when a user presses a button. In order to do this, I've created a restful method inside a controller on which I would like to inject the quartz scheduler, like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/triggerJob", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> triggerJob(@Qualifier StdSchedulerFactory schedulerFactory) {

        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();

            JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("statisticsJob",StatisticsJob.class);


            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger("new",0, 0));


        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

However, the job never gets scheduled, even after the code above is executed. What I am doing wrong? Is there another approach I could try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to autowire the SchedulerFactoryBean itself in my Controller and call the rescheduleJob method on the scheduler that is accessible through it:

```
@Autowired
private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory;

@RequestMapping(value = "/triggerJob", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> triggerJob() {
    try {
        schedulerFactory.getScheduler().triggerJob("statisticsJob", "default");
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```